# How to send ParseObject(back4app)to an array(model)?

Tags: android, arrays, android-recyclerview, back4app

I am trying to send a list of objects obtained from an API (back4app).
So far I can retrieve them in a string, but didnt manage to send that object to an array "Articles".
The documentation show you how to do it with an array of string, but this is not my case.

My Model class:
[image]

My read function, in MainActivity:

[image]

My Adapter class:

[image]

The array is like this:  List dataArticles = new ArrayList<>();

Cant find the solution to this problem, any idea?

Comment: try `dataArticles.add(articles)`

Comment: resolved, forget to update this answer :)